# mvc webpage without using the default templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 4.I have designed a webpage in Dreamweaver and then tried to convert it as a razor page. I wanted to view it in a browser, without using Visual Studio. I have heard that a Razor page can be edited using a notepad.

Please help, I am comfortable designing pages in Dreamweaver, than in Visual Studio.

Comment: The same way you would do it with the ASP.NET empty template if you didn't know ASP.NET. Read about MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have a HTML design (created in whichever tool you prefer) and you wish to create an MVC website out of this. You have experience in ASP.NET Webforms.

Primarily to creating anything I would follow the topics covered in the ASP.NET MVC tutorials of MVC itself. It's not about "default templates" it's about understanding what builds your final output. Layouts, partial renderings etc...

See http://www.asp.net/mvc

PS: Ask yourself: Is MVC the right choice for my solution? (because I get the feeling everyone just wants to use MVC and doesn't think about what it is and why you should or shouldn't use it...)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont't want to use default template then you can include your css files you created in Content folder. In shared folder which is located inside Views folder you can create the your customized layout which uses the css that you included in Content folder. And you can then include these layout in the views you later create inside shared folder of Views.

You can explore yourself by installing `twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample` from package manager console and see how your project changes.
This package changes your default layout to different layout, which is pretty cool.
Hope you can get idea of what is done and how you include your own layout from this above mentioned package.